# VSC Remote Server Works with Vite projects?

Tags: vite, vscode-remote

I can't get a Vite Project up and running on the VSCode remote, node based repositories run perfectly. The servers start but the url for the tunnel doesn't. I am using my computer as server in which vite is installed. Is there any other config needed? [Browser Screenshot accesing the tunnel's URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b622J.png)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try append `--host=0.0.0.0` in your `package.json` file at your dev command like so:

```json
{
 "name": "your project",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "scripts": {
  "dev": "vite dev --host=0.0.0.0",
  ...
 },
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this code in you vite.config.js:

```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
    import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

    // https://vitejs.dev/config/
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [react()],
      server:{
        host: true,
        open: true
      }
    })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).